# Mandrill Handlebars Template Date Formatting

Tags: handlebars.js, mandrill, email-templates

So, I'm working on a template where I have a merge variable, `dateSubmitted`. This variable comes from an API where it's formatted as so:

`dateSubmitted =  2017-09-13GMT22:25:45.513+00:00`

I'm trying to insert this date in a slightly nicer way into an email, so in my Mandrill template (using Handlebars) I'm doing the following:

`<li><em>Date Submitted:</em> {{date dateSubmitted}}</li>`

However, my date continues to display in the email as `2017-09-13GMT22:25:45.513+00:00`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Stumble upon this too. After an hour I re-read the docs, where is stated, that this inline helper is used to

> print the current date with a given format, defaults to d/m/Y

So, it is not for formatting your variables but for just displaying current date in custom format.

Comment: It's nice you pointed that out, but if you don't provide the correct answer for the problem, please leave it just as a comment in a comment section.

Comment: Ahhhh thank you. So, `date` is not the way to go! That's something.